# error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded! suggestion?

Tags: android, c++, build, rom

When trying to build a ROM it gives 2 errors:

**1)** `functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
extern "C" AudioPolicyInterface* createAudioPolicyManager(AudioPolicyClientInterface *clientInterface);
hardware/libhardware_legacy/include/hardware_legacy/AudioPolicyInterface.h:255:34: note: previous declaration is here`

**2)** `error: conflicting types for 'destroyAudioPolicyManager'
extern "C" void destroyAudioPolicyManager(AudioPolicyInterface *interface);

hardware/libhardware_legacy/include/hardware_legacy/AudioPolicyInterface.h:256:17: note: previous declaration is here`

Link for .h files: http://hastebin.com/polativede.cs

I really don't know what to change in order to fix this error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in the question itself instead of links to code.

Comment: Post a minimal but complete example. Don't link to off-site code.

Comment: sound's like the answer is right in the question.. if the only difference is the return value how will the compiler ever know witch one you refer to?

Comment: Links to off-site code that *augment* or provide context are acceptable.  But the question should work without having to follow any of them.

Comment: Edited the post as Users said..

Comment: Seems like there are two *alternate* include files. Are you including both?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm totally a noob on C++ and I haven't written that code. It was only a part of the source in order to build the ROM.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `extern "C"` for your function.

It means you are using **C linkage** for this function, and you cannot have another function with same name in your code.

If you have never heard about this, please refer this post
[In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)